# Why is callback function executed first in javascript?

Tags: javascript, callback

In the below example. *lname* is callback function inside *fname* function. When executed, first output is Smith and the Billy. As per my understanding, callback function *lname* should be executed once fname function is finished executing. Why am wrong here?

```js
function fname(){ console.log("Billy");}
function lname(){ console.log("Smith");}
fname(lname());
```

Comment: Because you're not passing `lname` as callback (function as argument), you're actually passing _the result of `lname`_ as argument...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the below example. `lname` is callback function inside `fname` function.

No, it is not. You are *invoking* `lname` (because you added the parentheses), and passing the result of its invocation (which happens to be `undefined`, as is the case any time a function does not explicitly `return` a value) to `fname`. Just like `Math.floor(Math.sqrt(10))` - there are no callbacks here. There is a big difference between `fname(lname())` and `fname(lname)`: the latter one passes a function itself into another function; and we'll call it a "callback" if it is, in fact, called back.

> As per my understanding, callback function `lname` should be executed once `fname` function is finished executing.

Again, no. A callback is executed when it is invoked, no more, no less. For example:

```js
function printsSomething() {
  console.log("Something");
}
function invokesCallbackAtEnd(callback) {
  console.log("invokesCallbackAtEnd doing something");
  callback();
}
function invokesCallbackAtStart(callback) {
  callback();
  console.log("invokesCallbackAtStart doing something");
}
function invokesCallbackAtStartAndEnd(callback) {
  callback();
  console.log("invokesCallbackAtStartAndEnd doing something");
  callback();
}
function invokesCallbackNever(callback) {
  console.log("invokesCallbackNever doing something");
}
invokesCallbackAtEnd(printsSomething); console.log("---");
invokesCallbackAtStart(printsSomething); console.log("---");
invokesCallbackAtStartAndEnd(printsSomething); console.log("---");
invokesCallbackNever(printsSomething); console.log("---");
```

Comment: If callback function is called back by outer most function, then what do it means when you say "A callback is executed when it is invoked, no more, no less." I understood from your example now, but still getting confused.

Comment: I mean a callback is called "callback" because it is meant to be "called back" from the function you passed it to, where "call" means the same as "invoke".

Answer (score 4):

The arguments to a function are evaluated before it's called. So `fname(lname())` results in `lname` being called, followed by `fname`. The result of `lname` is passed to `fname` as the first argument but it is not used by the called function.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't defining a callback function as such, to do so you will have to pass the reference to the function rather than the function call itself. i.e
`fname(lname);` And you have to change your `function fname` to

```
function fname (cb) {
  console.log("Billy");
  cb && cb.apply(this);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You did not pass `lname` as a callback function. You just invoked `lname` function and passed its return value `undefined`.

And even if you passed a callback function, its execution point depends on code.

```js
function fname(func) {
  func("Foo");
  console.log("Billy");
  func("Bar");
}

function lname() {
  console.log("Smith");
  return function (arg) { console.log(arg); }
}
fname(lname());
```